# php array getting placeholder from database

Tags: php, arrays

i have this designing my table:

```
<style type="text/css">
        tr {
            background: <?php echo $colors[$status];?>;
            color:white;
        }
</style>
```

and

```
    $status = $row[4];//value is 0
    $colors = array("lime", "red");
```

The value in the database is 0.

The `$status` variable defines what color the table row should be.  However the row is never lime.  Is my array wrong or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure the order is correct.

the order should be something like this:

```
<?php
    $status = $row[4];//value is 0
    $colors = array("lime", "red");
?>
<style type="text/css">
    tr {
        background: <?php echo $colors[$status];?>;
        color:white;
    }
</style>
```

your issue could be due to the fact that `$colors` was never declared before you started using it

Comment: ah silly mistake I did something else wrong I picked the wrong database lol. Thanks Neal I'll also rearrange stuff now.

Answer (score 0):

If your css is defined in a separate file like "style.css", then your server won't know to parse php code inside.  To do that you'll need to use the ".php" extension on your style file and include `<?php header('content-type:css);?>` at the top so the browser knows to interpret the css declarations.

Read more about using php in your css files here: http://www.barelyfitz.com/projects/csscolor/